# confidence interval for random forest regressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest, confidence-interval

i'm using a kaggle dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/harlfoxem/housesalesprediction) to make a prediction on house prices.

This is the code I used and so far so good.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn import metrics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

#import dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv(path_to_dataset)
dataset.head()

dataset['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['date']) #convert date in datetime 

#house_age is a new feature
dataset["house_age"] = dataset["date"].dt.year - dataset['yr_built']

#drop useful features
dataset=dataset.drop('date', axis=1)
dataset=dataset.drop('yr_built', axis=1)
dataset = dataset.drop(["id"],axis=1)

train, test = train_test_split(dataset, test_size=0.3, random_state=43)

xtrain = train.drop(['price'], axis = 1) #train array without price
ytrain = train['price'] #train array with price

xtest = test.drop(['price'], axis = 1) #test array without price
ytest = test['price']  #test array with price

reg = RandomForestRegressor()
reg.fit(xtrain,ytrain)

pred = reg.predict(xtest)

print("Score: ",r2_score(ytrain, reg.predict(xtrain)))
print("Score: ",r2_score(ytest, pred))
print('MSE: ', metrics.mean_squared_error(ytest, pred))
```

Now, however, I would like to calculate and draw a confidence interval for the predictions made with my model.

I have already tried to look at many articles and libraries for several hours but I have not yet been able to find a solution that works for my case.

These are a couple of the references I followed but with little success:

- http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/forest-confidence-interval/auto_examples/plot_mpg.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-mpg-py
- https://scikit-garden.github.io/examples/QuantileRegressionForests/#quantile-regression-forests_1

Does anyone know how to create a confidence interval for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

To construct confidence intervals, you can use the [quantile-forest](https://github.com/zillow/quantile-forest) package. Using the `RandomForestQuantileRegressor` method in the package, you can specify quantiles to estimate during training, which can then be used to construct intervals.

Here's an example that extends your code with the above package to do this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from quantile_forest import RandomForestQuantileRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# import dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv(path_to_dataset)
dataset.head()

dataset['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['date'])  # convert date in datetime

# house_age is a new feature
dataset['house_age'] = dataset["date"].dt.year - dataset['yr_built']

# drop useful features
dataset = dataset.drop('date', axis=1)
dataset = dataset.drop('yr_built', axis=1)
dataset = dataset.drop(['id'], axis=1)

train, test = train_test_split(dataset, test_size=0.3, random_state=43)

x_train = train.drop(['price'], axis=1)  # train array without price
y_train = train['price']  # train array with price

x_test = test.drop(['price'], axis=1)  # test array without price
y_test = test['price']  # test array with price

reg = RandomForestQuantileRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)
reg.fit(x_train, y_train)

# Get predictions at 95% prediction intervals and median.
y_pred = reg.predict(x_test, quantiles=[0.025, 0.5, 0.975])


def plot_intervals(y_true, y_pred_lower, y_pred_upper):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))

    y_pred_interval = y_pred_upper - y_pred_lower
    sort_idx = np.argsort(y_pred_interval)
    y_true = y_true[sort_idx]
    y_pred_lower = y_pred_lower[sort_idx]
    y_pred_upper = y_pred_upper[sort_idx]

    # Center data, with the mean of the prediction interval at 0.
    mean = (y_pred_lower + y_pred_upper) / 2
    y_true -= mean
    y_pred_lower -= mean
    y_pred_upper -= mean

    plt.plot(y_true, marker='.', ms=5, c='r', lw=0)
    plt.fill_between(
        np.arange(len(y_pred_upper)),
        y_pred_lower,
        y_pred_upper,
        alpha=0.2,
        color='gray',
    )
    plt.plot(np.arange(len(y_true)), y_pred_lower, marker='_', c='0.2', lw=0)
    plt.plot(np.arange(len(y_true)), y_pred_upper, marker='_', c='0.2', lw=0)
    plt.xlim([0, len(y_true)])
    plt.xlabel('Ordered Samples')
    plt.ylabel('Observed Values and Prediction Intervals (Centered)')

    plt.show()


plot_intervals(y_test.values, y_pred[:, 0], y_pred[:, 2])

print('Score: ', r2_score(y_train, reg.predict(x_train)))
print('Score: ', r2_score(y_test, y_pred[:, 1]))
print('MSE: ', mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred[:, 1]))
```

The code plots the generated intervals from smallest to largest along with the observed values:
[image: QRF with CIs on KC Dataset]

Comment: As an aside, if you're interested in housing data, I recommend the [King County Home Sales](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/andykrause/kingcountysales) dataset on Kaggle, which is a more comprehensive and up-to-date analogue to the House Sales in King County dataset you're using.