# Prediction intervals for DesicionTreeRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, confidence-interval

I am trying to find a way to get prediction intervals for `sklearn` `DecisionTreeRegressor`.
I have a categorical input variable and the target value is numeric.

Simple executable script:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
import pandas as pd
from quantile_forest import RandomForestQuantileRegressor

data = {'App':  ['Tiktok', 'Instagram', 'Twitter', 'Tiktok', 'Instagram', 'Twitter', 'Tiktok'],
    'TimeSpent': ['50', '40', '20', '50', '45', '30', '40']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
X = df['App']
X = pd.get_dummies(X, columns = ['App']).astype('category')
y = df[['TimeSpent']].astype('float')

model = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=44)
model = model.fit(X,y)

#Prediction for Tiktok
y_pred = pd.DataFrame(0, index = range(1), columns = X.columns)
y_pred.at[0, 'Tiktok'] = 1

model.predict(y_pred)
```

I could use `RandomForestQuantileRegressor` as shown here [confidence interval for random forest regressor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72734946/confidence-interval-for-random-forest-regressor/72877544#72877544), but I'm not sure if it's right and performant to use  randomforest method in the first place and also 25 and 75 Qs for prediction intervals.

Any suggestions on how to get the prediction intervals for time spent in the Tiktok app?

Comment: So your first question is if it's right to use a random forest instead of a single tree?

Comment: Yes, statistically. Also, if it is as performant as the decision tree -  clearly it takes much longer to run.

Answer (score 0):

The use of quantile regression forests (QRFs) for producing prediction intervals is backed by [a rigorous paper](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume7/meinshausen06a/meinshausen06a.pdf) that proposed the method. In the paper, the author proves that, given some assumptions, quantile regression forests are a consistent way of estimating conditional distributions and quantile functions. This has also been borne out by further adaptations of random forests, such as [generalized random forests](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-47/issue-2/Generalized-random-forests/10.1214/18-AOS1709.full), which build conceptually on the QRF framework.

In practice, the quality of the prediction intervals will depend on the accuracy of the model and the degree to which the training data is representative of the data distribution. Also, with very large datasets, QRFs can become slow at inference, though there tend to be some tricks that speed this up without sacrificing the consistency of the method (e.g., randomly sampling only one value per leaf node).

In my own experience, QRFs tend to work quite well for generating prediction intervals on small- and medium-sized datasets. They also offer the flexibility of choosing the quantiles to estimate at prediction time, rather than defining them during the model initialization. They also tend to be competitive with CV-based approaches like [MAPIE](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/MAPIE) or, I expect, the bootstrap approach in [Doubt](https://github.com/saattrupdan/doubt), though lack the flexibility of being model-agnostic (obviously).